# Nginx - Proxy subdirectory to remote server

Tags: nginx

I have two servers (`server1` and `server2`) listening for the same domain name. Let's say `www.example.com`.

`server1` acts as the main one, where the domain itself is pointed to.

What I'm trying to do is proxy all requests to a specific subdirectory on `server1` to `server2`

This is my current configuration on `server1`, where `xx.xxx.x.xxx` is the IP of `server2`:

```
server
{
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    # proxy to port 81 on server1
    location /
    {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:81;
    }

    # proxy to server2
    location /subdirectory
    {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:80;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host www.example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Right now I'm getting `504 Gateway Time-out`

Answer (score 0):

This settings is not the best way, the latency is overkill.
Anyway you need to set the correctly timeout (default is 60s)

```
proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
proxy_read_timeout 90s;
proxy_send_timeout 90s;
```

Ref:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html